# MVC Edit form with dynamic dropdown list - How to set initial values

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC , C# and Entity Framework.
The object on my model are:

**State**-------- Id , Name

**City** ------- Id , Name , StateId

**TheObject**----Id, Name, StateId, CityId

I want to create an edit form for **TheObject**.
The Edit form has 2 dropdownlist State and City that are created dynamically , and the City list depend on selection made on State List.
The problem is that the dropdown list are filled correctly , but when the edit form is open these 2 dropdownlist are in empty state and does not have selected the real values for the object that is edited .

The partial code for Edit view is this :

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(u => u.State, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.State,
          new SelectList(ViewBag.State, "Id", "Name"),
          "Choose State",
          new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "selectCities()" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(u => u.City, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.City,
   new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Id", "Name"),
          "Choose City",
          new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

function selectCities() {
    debugger;
    var stateId = $("#State").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/selectCities',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'application/json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ stateId: +stateId }),
        success: function (result) {
            $("#City").html("");
            $("#City").append
            ($('<option></option>').val(null).html("---choose City---"));
            $.each($.parseJSON(result), function (i, cty)
            { $("#City").append($('<option></option>').val(cty.Id).html(cty.Name)) })

        },
        error: function () { alert("Error !") },
    });
}
```

The partial code of the controller is this :

```
private void Fill_StateDropDownList()
    {
        var st = from d in db.States
                  orderby d.Name
                  select d;
        ViewBag.State = st.ToList();
    }

  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult selectCities(string stId)   
    {  

       List < City > lstcity = new List < City > ();  
        int stateiD = Convert.ToInt32(stId);
        lstgrupet = (from d in db.Citys
                  where d.StateID==stateiD
                 select d).ToList();  
       string result= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstgrupet, Formatting.Indented,
       new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore});
       return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    } 

public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
      TheObject obj = db.TheObjects.Find(id);
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        Fill_StateDropDownList()            
        return View(obj);
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditPost(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var theobjectToUpdate = db.TheObjects.Find(id);

        if (TryUpdateModel(theobjectToUpdate, "",
           new string[] { "Name","StateId","CityId" }))
        {
                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error.");
                }

        }
        Fill_StateDropDownList()
        return View(theobjectToUpdate);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

actually `SelectList` has a construct with a parameter called `selectedValue`

now you should know how to do it

in edit View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.State, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.State,
      new SelectList(ViewBag.State, "Id", "Name", Model.State),
      "Choose State",
      new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "selectCities()" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not work , still the State and City dropdownlists are in empty state , so the values for the current edit object are not selected.

Comment: @Adriano - You have to populate u.State with the selected value.

Comment: @Erik Can you show me please how can I do this ?

Comment: you stored Id in Model.State or you stored the object? if it’s the object, try Model.State.Id. anyway, assign a value to the parameter which can be found in the options value of the select

Comment: @Ray I have used like this .... Model.StateID , and does not work.

Comment: it works fine on my side, but in my case the option values are string, maybe you can try to convert them also

Comment: @Ray Just for try , instead of Model.StateID , I put the value , 11 or "11" , but still the dropdownlist remain with no selected item.

Comment: @Adriano - In your controller, you set the value of State in your model.  Something like `return View(new MyModel() { State = myvalue });`

Comment: If you read my code above : TheObject obj = db.TheObjects.Find(id);
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        Fill_StateDropDownList()            
        return View(obj);

Answer (score 0):

You already have the saved state and city values. All you have to do is to load the subset of cities based on the saved state id and use that collection to render the dropdown for cities

The `DropDownListFor` helper method will select the corresponding option from the SELECT element as long as the view model's City property value matches with one of the option's value attribute value.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    TheObject obj = db.TheObjects.Find(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    Fill_StateDropDownList() 
    FillCities(obj.State);           
    return View(obj);
}
private void FillCities(int stateId)
{
   ViewBag.CityList = db.Cities
                       .Where(g => g.StateId== stateId)
                       .Select(f => new SelectListItem() { 
                                                            Value = f.Id.ToString(), 
                                                            Text = f.Name })
                       .ToList();
}
```

Make an adjustment to the view

```
var cityList = new List<SelectListItem>();
if (ViewBag.CityList != null)
{
    cityList =ViewBag.CityList as List<SelectListItem>;
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.City, cityList , "Choose City")
```

Another option is to make an ajax call on the page load (document ready to get the cities based on the value of state dropdown). It gets complicated if you have multiple nested dropdowns.(ends up in callback hell)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155188/discussion-on-answer-by-shyju-mvc-edit-form-with-dynamic-dropdown-list-how-to). Please ensure that relevant information from the chat is incorporated back into either the question or answer, as appropriate.